# German umlauts not showing in Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, listbox, special-characters

I've been facing a problem with Zend Form, for some reason words that have german special characters do not show in the dropbox. 
for the form I'm using this partial code:

```
 $country_to = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('country_to');
    $country_to->setLabel('Traveling To (Country)')
            ->addMultiOptions($this->country_list);
```

And I'm getting it from the DB like this:

```
protected $country_list = array();
protected function getCountryValues()
{
    $mapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_Resource();
    $resources = $mapper->fetchAllCountries();

    $this->country_list[''] = '';
    foreach($resources as $resource){
        $this->country_list[$resource->getName()] = $resource->getName();
    }
}
```

and the result I'm getting is this:
[image]

I dumped the country_list and it actually contains all data but it's not showing in the form!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was pretty simple. I need to disable the default escaping by zend.
I simply added this to the beginning of the form and it worked:

```
$this->getView()->setEscape('stripslashes');
```

Comment: What you've done is changed the escaping function to stripslashes. Since this is not an escaping function you may have introduced an XSS vulnerability into your application. It is much more likely that you have a character set mismatch between your db, application and/or db connection. This would cause the default escaping function (htmlspecialchars) to error, since this function is charset aware, but stripslashes isn't. You'd be better off trying to fix the real problem if you can.